# How to send all traffic over a VPN connection?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, vpn

I am creating an application to connect to a VPN server.

I have worked out how to do this, but need to be able to send all traffic over the connection.

Is there any code which can do this?

So far I have tried:

```
    let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
    var p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
    manager.`protocol` = p
    let pw = ""
    println(manager.connection.status)
    p.username = ""
    p.passwordReference = pw.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    p.serverAddress = ""
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
    //p.sharedSecretReference = getPasscodeNSData("vpnSharedSecret")
    p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
    p.disconnectOnSleep = false
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is any way to switch all system IP traffic over a VPN connection. Apple doesn't let apps muck around with the OS like that.

Comment: [OpenVPN](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981?mt=8). Also the new [network extensions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=717) in iOS 9, but the docs have not been released yet.